# Back button no longer shows arrow

Tags: button, uno-platform

I have a back button implemented like so:

`<Button x:Name="BackButton" Click="Back_Click" Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"/>`

This worked fine until upgrading to Uno 3.1.  Now my back button shows as a box with a question mark inside of it.  I believe this means it is not able to find the font.  I did upgrade to the uno-fluentui-assets font as mentioned in the documentation.  How do I make this work now?  If someone has a suggestion of another approach to putting a back arrow on a button- I would be fine doing that as well.  Thank you.

Comment: On which platform(s) is it not displaying correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your response- you were right- I had missed a step.  So- if someone else makes a similar mistake, the instructions say to modify the info.plist and replace the old font name with the new one.  Dont double click on info.plist- right click on it and select open with.  Then select XML (Text) Encoder.  Ignore the warning about inconsistent line endings.  Scroll down and replace the font name there.  My Android head was fine- I missed that when I posted yeseterday.  Hopefully this helps and thank you to David for taking a look and giving me the sound advice that I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You should double-check that you followed all the steps in the [font upgrade documentation](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/uno-fluent-assets.html). I wasn't able to replicate your problem - the snippet of code you posted displays correctly on iOS, Android, and WebAssembly, using `Uno.UI 3.1.0-dev.536` and a blank app created with the latest version of the [Uno app template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nventivecorp.uno-platform-addin) (which includes the Uno Fluent Assets font).

If you create a new blank app with the latest template, you can check how the font is integrated there and double-check that it matches what you did with your own app.